# Getting Error : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Tags: android

I have implemented search function to get details of clients  but when i select the searched item it gives me an error of

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
```

so on

This is my code i am using Json to search my clients details and storing in array but when i search the data and select it i get the above error. Please help me out .Thank You

```
     public void RunSearchClientService() {
        //progressDialog.show();

        JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.POST, Network.API_URL + "clients/search", api_parameter, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject result = ((JSONObject) response.get("data"));
                            JSONArray clients = (JSONArray) result.get("clients");
                            JSONArray invoice_lines = (JSONArray) result.get("invoice_lines");

                            Integer invoice_number = helper_string.optInt(result, "invoice_number");

                            logoImage = helper_string.optString(result, "logo");

                            if (invoice_number > 0) {
                                edit_invoice_number.setText(String.format("%04d", invoice_number));
                                toolbar.setTitle(String.format("INV-%04d", invoice_number));
                            }

                            array_list_clients.clear();
                            array_clients = new String[clients.length()];

                            Integer selected_client_index = 0;

                            if (clients.length() > 0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < clients.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject obj = clients.getJSONObject(i);

                                    Client client = new Client();

                                    client.Id = obj.optInt("id");
                                    client.UserId = obj.optInt("user_id");
                                    client.Name = helper_string.optString(obj, "name");
                                    client.Reg_Num = obj.optString("reg_num");
                                    client.Email = helper_string.optString(obj, "email");
                                    client.Address1 = helper_string.optString(obj, "address1");
                                    client.Address2 = helper_string.optString(obj, "address2");
                                    client.City = helper_string.optString(obj, "city");
                                    client.State = helper_string.optString(obj, "state");
                                    client.Postcode = helper_string.optString(obj, "postcode");
                                    client.Country = helper_string.optString(obj, "country");

                                    array_list_clients.add(client);
                                    array_clients[i] = client.Name + " " + "Reg No. : "+ client.Reg_Num ;

                                    if (currentInvoice != null && currentInvoice.ClientId == client.Id) {
                                        selected_client_index = i;
                                        currentClient = client;
                                    }

                                    /*if (obj.optInt("invoice_number") > 0)
                                        invoice_number = obj.optInt("invoice_number");*/
                                }

                                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(NewInvoiceActivity.this, R.layout.custom_simple_spinner_item, array_clients);
                                spinner_client.setAdapter(adapter);
                                spinner_client.setSelection(selected_client_index);
                            }

                            if (invoice_lines.length() > 0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < invoice_lines.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject obj = invoice_lines.getJSONObject(i);

                                    Item item = new Item();
                                    item.Id = obj.optInt("id");
                                    item.Quantity = obj.optInt("quantity");
                                    item.Name = helper_string.optString(obj, "name");
                                    item.Rate = obj.optDouble("rate");
                                    item.Description = helper_string.optString(obj, "description");

                                    array_list_items.add(item);
                                }

                                calculate_total();
                                setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(list_items);
                            }

                            if (array_list_items_from_intent != null && array_list_items_from_intent.size() > 0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < array_list_items_from_intent.size(); i++) {
                                    array_list_items.add(array_list_items_from_intent.get(i));
                                }

                                calculate_total();
                                setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(list_items);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            Toast.makeText(NewInvoiceActivity.this, R.string.error_try_again_support, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

//                        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
//                            // If the response is JSONObject instead of expected JSONArray
//                            progressDialog.dismiss();
//                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                            // If the response is JSONObject instead of expected JSONArray
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }

                        NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                        if (response != null && response.data != null) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(new String(response.data));
                                //   Toast.makeText(NewInvoiceActivity.this, json.has("message") ? json.getString("message") : json.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                                Toast.makeText(NewInvoiceActivity.this, R.string.error_try_again_support, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            //  Toast.makeText(NewInvoiceActivity.this, error != null && error.getMessage() != null ? error.getMessage() : error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("X-API-KEY", MainActivity.api_key);
                return params;
            }
        };

        // Get a RequestQueue
        RequestQueue queue = MySingleton.getInstance(NewInvoiceActivity.this).getRequestQueue();

        //Used to mark the request, so we can cancel it on our onStop method
        postRequest.setTag(TAG);

        MySingleton.getInstance(NewInvoiceActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(postRequest);
    }
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you searched for this error to understand why it happens?

Comment: I have searched for this but can't able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1 means your array at index 1 is not valid; in other words, you are trying to access the second element of an array that has only one element.

The below code will give a similar error:

```
public class ReplicateError { 
    public static void main(String args[]) {
     // reproducing java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException : 1 error 
     String[] clients = {"John"}; 
     String client = clients[1]; 
     // this will throw java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException : 1 
     System.out.println(client); 
     } 
}
```

I suggest you do a bound check:

```
if (args.length < 2) { 
  System.err.println("Not enough arguments received."); 
  return; 
}
```